# Using .9.png image with phonegap or cordova project inside www res folder with .html css file

Tags: android, cordova

how to use the .9.png images in phonegap application kept inside www folder with .html file.
I Have kept the .9.png file inside www res android folder

but not able to utilize it like the layout files on android native application

Answer (score 0):

You can put your images in **res/drawable** like native app and set image src to
`file:///android_res/drawable/myimage.png`

location to access the image file. Android will pick the right image based on the dpi.